# How to change of web page content from a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message

I am writing extension which will underline accent in English words on web pages.
I've got stuck after I click "Search" button on popup, nothing seems to happen.

Here's the scenario:

1. user double click a word on a web page.
2. the whole word is marked.
3. user clicks extension icon on chrome browser bar.
4. a popup is shown. Input field in popup is filled in with the marked word.
5. user adds accent.  Ie. if marked word is 'boundary', in popup's input field there will be: 'boudary' displayed. Then user modify the input value to: 'boudary,bo' (without quotes).
6. user click "Search" button on popup.
7. letters "bo" in "boundary" word on page are being underlined.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "jquery.highlight-4.js", "selection.js" ],
    "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls\u003E" ]
  } ],
  "name": "Mark accent",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "Marks accent in english words for selected word on page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage", "file:///*" ]
}
```

**app.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) {
    $("#t1").val(response.data);
    console.log('input t1 value: ' + $("#t1").val(response.data));
  });
});
$("#t1").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    $("#search_btn").click();
  }
});
$("#t1").focus();

function search(that) {
  var token = new String (t1.value);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"$(document.body).highlight('"+token+"','text-decoration:underline')"});
  window.close();
}
```

**selection.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<style>
body {
overflow: hidden; margin: 5px; padding: 0px; background: black;color: white;
width: 300px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
Please enter the word to highlight :
<input type="text" id="t1"/>
  <button onclick="search(this)" id="search_btn">Search</button>
  <button onclick="hl_clear(this)" id="clear_btn">Clear all highlights</button>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.highlight-4.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**jquery.highlight-4.js**

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat, fbgcolor) {
  function innerHighlight(node, pat, fbgcolor) {
    var skip = 0;
    var array = pat.split(',');
    var sWord = array[0];
    var accent = array[1];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(sWord);
      if (pos >= 0) {
        var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
        var endbit = middlebit.splitText(sWord.length);
        var pos2 = middlebit.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(accent);
        if (pos2 >= 0) {
          var spannode = document.createElement('span');
          spannode.className = 'highlight';
          fbgcolor += ";padding: 0px; margin: 0px;";
          spannode.setAttribute('style', fbgcolor);
          var middlebit2 = middlebit.splitText(pos2);
          var endbit2 = middlebit2.splitText(accent.length);
          var middleclone2 = middlebit2.cloneNode(true);
          spannode.appendChild(middleclone2);
          middlebit2.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit2);
        }
        skip = 1;
      }
    }
    else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && 
             !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat, fbgcolor);
      }
    }
    return skip;
  }
  return this.each(function() {
    innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase(), fbgcolor);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working after so many modifications and eliminated non-chrome extension related content. You can add your content to this skeleton.

Do not add Inline scripts in html
`<button onclick="search(this)" id="search_btn">Search</button>`

[image]

Basic Skeleton of your code:

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "jquery.highlight-4.js", "selection.js" ],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
  } ],
  "name": "Mark accent",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Marks accent in english words for selected word on page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ]
}
```

***app.js***

```
function search(that) {
    console.log("Search is clicked");
  var token = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  console.log(token);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"highlight();"});
  //window.close();
}
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById("search_btn").onclick=search;

};
```

***selection.js***

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
overflow: hidden; margin: 5px; padding: 0px; background: black;color: white;
width: 300px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>
Please enter the word to highlight :
<input type="text" id="t1"/>
  <button id="search_btn">Search</button>
  <button id="">Clear all highlights</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***jquery.highlight-4.js***

```
function highlight(){
    console.log("Highlight is called");
}
```

Let me know if it is still failing.

Comment: I've added code from my question into the skeleton and it works fine now :-) Thank you Sudarshan.